# How do I switch between Scala's SDKs in IntelliJ?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, intellij-14

You can install multiple scala SDKs in IntelliJ, but how do you know which one is used when your code is compiled? How do you switch between them? The interface allows you to add or remove SDKs, but it does not have "Use as default".

Comment: See the Scala library that is in your module dependencies: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html.

Comment: Yes, but this gives only the list of SDKs. It does not tell you which one is used for your project.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution is to re-import the project and overwrite the configuration of IntelliJ.

You can verify which Scala SDK you use with:

```
println(util.Properties.versionString)
```